# Multi-Project Gradle with SonarQube plugin not publishing results

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

The build itself works. When I execute:

```
"gradlew -i clean sonarqube"
```

I can see in the output that sonar is running through all of the child project and it says it has completed successfully. On the SonarQube Server all it has is:

**No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration.**

Key
com.my.org:my-project:my_branch

Here is my root gradle script.

```
    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
            classpath ("org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+")
            classpath ("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2.1")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

    allprojects {
        group = 'com.my.group'
        version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    subprojects {
        ext {
            javaV = '1.8'
            swaggerV = '1.5.10'
        }

        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: "jacoco"
        apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

        compileJava {
            sourceCompatibility = javaV
            targetCompatibility = javaV
        }

        dependencies {
            compile ("io.swagger:swagger-core:${swaggerV}")
            compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.4.0")
            compile ("com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1")
        }

        dependencyManagement {
            imports {
                mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.RELEASE"
            }
        }
    }
```

Gradle version is 3.2.1

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look at analysis logs on server side (Administration -> Background tasks) to see if the analysis report is properly received and processed.